# Why is Grails taking the jar dependencies instead of the existing maven project dependencies?

Tags: grails

I'm using IntelliJ IDEA 10.0.2 (with groovy/grails support), maven 2.2.1 and grails 1.3.6.

We have a big maven project, which depends on many other maven projects. Let's say the workspace structure looks as follows:

- backend-project (Java project, without further project dependencies)
- output-project (Java project, without further project dependencies)
- frontend-project (Grails project, which dependes on both, backend and output)

That means, within my frontend-project's pom.xml I have defined 2 Project Dependencies:

e.g.

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>com.company.project</groupId>
   <artifactId>backend-project</artifactId>
   <version>${project.version}</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
   <groupId>com.company.project</groupId>
   <artifactId>output-project</artifactId>
   <version>${project.version}</version>
</dependency>
```

Let's assume that I change some Java Source within the output or backend project. When I 
run the grails application now, then it won't consider the changes. I have to publish the changed artifact locally and then resolve it again by the grails project before running the application in order to take effect.
This tells me that the grails project just depends on the project dependency jars within the maven repository and does not care about any existing project dependency "sources" within the workspace.

Does it have to be that complicated and if so, why?

Note that if my frontend project was a spring web project, the changes will be seen in IDEA and tomcat will even reload the change dynamically.

Note that when IDEA recognizes a mavenized grails project, it won't run the grails project with: "grail run-app" anymore but with a more complicated version of: "mvn grails:exec -Dcommand=run-app". Don't know if this is of any relevance..

Thanks!
Mr. Slash

Answer (score 0):

Maven always picks up the jar files from the repositories (local and then remote etc depending on your pom.xml config).

Think about it: How would your main project know where the backend-project or the output-project files are located?

If you want a direct dependency then remove it from pom.xml and modify the project build path to directly add the projects' outputs to your main projects. In Eclipse open the properties page of the main project => build path => projects => add.

Comment: I understand that maven acts as you said when I want to build my project, but since I'm just running the application locally, it doesn't really need to depend on the libraries..

Comment: I understand that maven acts as you said when I want to build my project, but since I'm just running the application locally, it doesn't really need to depend on the libraries..

The point is, that eclipse doesn't really care about the pom.xml files and builds it's own project files. But IDEA builds it's project files based on the information found in the pom.xml and tries to hold them in synch. 

And as I said:
If my frontend project was a spring web project, the changes will be seen in IDEA and tomcat will even reload the change dynamically.

But thx anyway!